# react-select to just include values in form, rather than value: '' and label: ''

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, acts-as-taggable-on, react-select

I'm including `react-select` in my rails project, within a `redux-form`, it all works well, except that the backend I'm submitting the form to doesn't like the `{value, label}`,

I'd like my form field to just include a list of the values.

here's my form code:

```
export const renderTagsSelect = props => {
  const { input, initialValues } = props;
  return (
    <Creatable
      {...props}
      value={input.value || initialValues}
      resetValue={initialValues}
      onChange={value => input.onChange(value)}
      onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
    />
  );
};

render() {
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(doSaveItem)}>
    <Title>Modifica Item</Title>
    <Field
      name="title"
      label="Titolo"
      component={renderInput}
      validate={required()}
    />
    <br />
    <span>Tags</span>
    <br />
    <TagsFormSelector name="tag_list" tags={item.tag_list} />
    <SubmitButton type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
      Salva modifiche
    </SubmitButton>
  </form>
}
```

when submitting, the JSON generated by the form is like:

```
 "tag_list": [
    {
      "label": "cena",
      "value": "cena"
    },
    {
      "label": "Paesaggi cittadini",
      "value": "Paesaggi cittadini"
    }
  ],
```

my backend is implemented in rails with `acts_as_taggable_on`, prefers to receive just something like this:

```
"tag_list: ["cena", "Paesaggi cittadini"]
```

for non-optimised this could be, I prefer having the backend drive the API.

Any clues how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following kuiro5 suggestion I fixed it in the form with a `normaliseData` function:

in the `form`:

```
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(doSaveItem)}>
        [..]
        <TagsFormSelector name="js_tag_list" tags={item.tag_list} />
        [..]
```

in the `doSaveItem`:

```
const doSaveItem = (data, dispatch, props) => {
  normaliseData(data);

  return dispatch(saveItem(props.item.id, data)).catch(response => {
    throw new SubmissionError(f.errorsFromProps(response));
  });
};
```

the `normaliseData`:

```
const normaliseData = data => {
  data["js_tag_list"] &&
    (data["tag_list"] = data["js_tag_list"].map(tag => tag.value));
```

and other data normalisations.

this made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just pass a function reference to the `onSubmit` prop, you can create a new function that formats your data before calling `handleSubmit`:

```
  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
```

And in your `onSubmit` function:

```
onSubmit = (tags) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  const submitValues = tags.map((tag) => tag.value);

  handleSubmit(submitValues); // you can also pass doSaveItem here
}
```